# Comparing dates in Java - only years, months and days

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to compare to dates object. Only one problem is that I want to compare just days, month and years.

```
/* toString output
mydate 2013-08-23
current date: Thu Aug 23 14:15:34 CEST 2013
```

If I compare just days ( 23-08-2013 ) dates are equal, if I'm using .after() .before() methods
dates are diffrent.

Is there is Java method that compares only days, month, years in easy way or do I have to compare each value ?

Comment: Please post the code you're using! It might seem simple to you, but we're going to really struggle to answer if you don't post a minimum working example (MWE)!

Comment: Just parse it into a `Calendar` and then set the hours/minutes/seconds to zero.

Comment: @chrylis be careful with time zone too!

Comment: @Pureferret actually this is code date = new Date(); date.before(date2); second date is loaded from DB

Comment: @LaurentG _holds head and cries softly that `java.sql.Date` comes first in autocomplete_

Comment: I read all answers, and think all are good i've decided to go with JodaTime

Answer (score 23):

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTime(date1);
cal2.setTime(date2);
boolean sameDay = cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
              cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

This will work perfectly.........

Comment: I've never thought about comparing "DAY_OF_YEAR", nice way of think.

Answer (score 4):

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is much better and highly recommended. But if you have to use Java api, you can do-

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();

c1.setTime(someDate);
c2.setTime(someOtherDate);

int yearDiff = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR) - c2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int monthDiff = c1.get(Calendar.MONTH) - c2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int dayDiff = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Say to compare only year, you can do-

```
if(c1.get(Calendar.YEAR) > c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)){
    // code
}
```

etc.

Comment: The best way is to simply compare the integer value of Date objects refactored to represent local day numbers.

Comment: @scottb You shoud not be using deprecated methods.

Comment: No deprecated methods have been used.

Comment: The solution to this problem, assuming that one begins with Date objects representing the two instants that are to be compared, can be accomplished entirely with integer arithmetic.

Comment: @scottb Following your logic, the entire problem of writing Java programs can be accomplished by programming assembly language. We humans use abstractions to help in our thinking. Manipulating date-time with a count from epoch is asking for trouble. For one thing, there are many different [epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29). For another, there are different counts: Seconds in Unix, Milliseconds in java.util.Date & Joda-Time, Nanoseconds in the java.date package, and Microseconds in others. Yet another: verifying and debugging count-from-epoch values is difficult.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use external libraries and there is no problem using Calendar you could try something like this:

```
Calendar calendar1= Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendar2= Calendar.getInstance();

Date date1 = ...;
Date date2= ...;

calendar1.setTime(date1);
calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

calendar2.setTime(date2);
calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

calendar1.after(calendar2);
calendar1.before(calendar2);
```

Not so simple but is something...

Comment: Upon instantiation `Calendar` will be initialized to the current date already, thus for `currentCalendar` setting time to `currentDate` is unnecessary.

Comment: This doesn't work 100% of the time. Had a use case where I did that and the calendar.getTime() would still return the time with the hours set as the parameter date. Best to clear the fields and set only the year, month and day ones.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, date support in the core Java API is very weak. You could use `Calendar` to strip time/timezone information from your date. You'd probably want to write a separate method to do that. You could also use the Joda API for date/time support, as it's much better than Java's.

Answer (score 3):

```
Date date = new Date();
String str="2013-08-23";
Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(str);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTime(date1);

if(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR)){
System.out.println("Years are equal");
}
else{
System.out.println("Years not equal");
}

if(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH)){
System.out.println("Months are equal");
}
else{
System.out.println("Months not equal");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

> I want to compare just days, month and years.
>
> mydate 2013-08-23
>
> current date: Thu Aug 23 14:15:34 CEST 2013

If you want to capture the current date dynamically.

```
LocalDate.now(                   // Capture the current date…
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" )  // …as seen by the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
)
.isEqual(
    LocalDate.parse( "2013-08-23" ) 
)
```

Or, for a specific moment.

```
ZonedDateTime.of(  // Thu Aug 23 14:15:34 CEST 2013
    2013 , 8 , 23 , 14 , 15 , 34 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" )     
)
.toLocalDate()     // Extract the date only, leaving behind the time-of-day and the time zone.
.isEqual(
    LocalDate.parse( "2013-08-23" ) 
)
```

## `LocalDate`

The bundled java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. As other answers suggested, use a decent date-time libary. That means either:

- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
  [LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class
- java.time package of Java 8 (JSR 310)
  [LocalDate](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class

You need to extract a date-only value from your date-time, to ignore the time-of-day. Both Joda-Time and java.time have such a class, coincidentally named `LocalDate`.

### java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );

ZonedDateTime x = ZonedDateTime.of( 2014, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, zoneId );
ZonedDateTime y = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
```

Extract and compare the date-only portion of the date-time by calling [`toLocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toLocalDate--).

```
Boolean isSameDate = x.toLocalDate().isEqual( y.toLocalDate() );
```

### Joda-Time

```
DateTimeZone timeZoneParis = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );

DateTime x = new DateTime( 2014, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, timeZoneParis );
DateTime y = new DateTime( 2014, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, timeZoneParis );

boolean isXAfterY = x.isAfter( y );
```

To test equality of the date portion, convert the DateTime objects to a [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) which describes only a date without any time-of-day or time zone (other than a time zone used to decide the date).

```
boolean isSameDate = x.toLocalDate().isEqual( y.toLocalDate() );
```

If you want to examine the constituent elements, Joda-Time offers methods such as [dayOfMonth](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#dayOfMonth%28%29), hourOfDay, and more.

Comment: I totally agree with using java.time when in Java 8.  
To convert from java.util.Date to LocalDate I usually do this:
    date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();  
And to convert back to Date
   Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());  
But you can also use a different ZoneId as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No there is nothing in the JDK. You could use some external library as [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). There is a method [`DateUtils.isSameDay(Date, Date)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#isSameDay%28java.util.Date,%20java.util.Date%29) which would do what you are looking for.

Better would be to avoid to use the `Date` of Java and use for instance [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Comment: Actually, there is a way in the Java date/time API, and it is suprprisingly easy.

Comment: If you are talking about your answer. I don't find it *easy*. And I don't know any method like `isSameDay` in the JDK.

Comment: The point is that the assertion that "No there is nothing in the JDK" is false.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way

```
    String str="2013-08-23";
    Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(str);
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    Calendar calNow=Calendar.getInstance();

    if(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)>calNow.get(Calendar.YEAR)){
        // do something
    }if(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)>calNow.get(Calendar.MONTH)){
        // do something
    }if(cal.get(Calendar.DATE)>calNow.get(Calendar.DATE)){
       // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    Date d1= ...
    Date d2= ...
    long dayInMillis = 24 * 3600 * 1000; 
    boolean dateEqual = d1.getTime() / dayInMillis == d2.getTime() / dayInMillis;
```

Comment: The reason that this solution is fallible is that Dates represent instants always in UTC, which means some offset gets added to local time.  When this happens, it is possible for two instants on the same day in local time to be refactored into two instants on different days in UTC.  To make the most accurate comparison, the Dates need to be offset back to local time before the local time information is truncated away.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is surprisingly simple.  You'll need to begin by parsing your date time strings into Date instants in the Java API (you can use a SimpleDateFormat object to help you do this).

If you have two instants in time represented as Dates:

1. Get the representation of both as long integers
2. Because all Dates are represented internally in UTC, adjust both to the local time zone by adding or substracting the offsets from GMT +/- DST
3. Convert both to an integer count of days (which will include the granularity for comparing years and months)
4. Compare them by their natural order; if the integers are equal, the day, month, and year are equal irrespective of local time (assuming, of course, that both Date instants were in the same time zone).

Presto!

A method for adjusting a Date object to local time and returning it as a decimal count of days in the POSIX Epoch follows:

```
public static double toLocalDayNumber(Date d, GregorianCalendar gc) {

        gc.setTime(d);

        long utcDateAsMillisFromEpoch = gc.getTimeInMillis();
        long localDateAsMillisFromEpoch = utcDateAsMillisFromEpoch +
                gc.get(GregorianCalendar.ZONE_OFFSET) +
                gc.get(GregorianCalendar.DST_OFFSET);

        return (((double) localDateAsMillisFromEpoch) / (86400.0 * 1000.0);
}
```

This method takes a Date object `d`, and a Java API Calendar object `gc` that has been constructed with the local TimeZone of interest.

Answer (score 0):

By using `Date` only

```
        SimpleDateFormat cDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
        Date now1 = new Date();
        String ccDate1 = cDate1.format(now1);
        System.out.println("Date1=="+ccDate1);


        SimpleDateFormat cDate2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-sss");
        Date now2 = new Date();
        String ccDate2 = cDate2.format(now2);
        System.out.println("Date2=="+ccDate2);

        if(ccDate1.equals(ccDate2))//Get full feature of date
            System.out.println("Equal");
        else
            System.out.println("Not Equal");

        if(ccDate1.split(" ")[0].equals(ccDate2.split(" ")[0]))//Comparing  Full Date
            System.out.println("Equal");
        else
            System.out.println("Not Equal");

        if(ccDate1.split(" ")[0].split("-")[0].equals(ccDate2.split(" ")[0].split("-")[0]))//Comparing YEAR
            System.out.println("Equal");
        else
            System.out.println("Not Equal");

        if(ccDate1.split(" ")[0].split("-")[1].equals(ccDate2.split(" ")[0].split("-")[1]))//Comparing MONTH
            System.out.println("Equal");
        else
            System.out.println("Not Equal");

        if(ccDate1.split(" ")[0].split("-")[2].equals(ccDate2.split(" ")[0].split("-")[2]))//Comparing DAY
            System.out.println("Equal");
        else
            System.out.println("Not Equal");
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat uses a Calendar instance internally, so you don't really avoid the creation of a Calendar, which is known to be not very performant. Also keep in mind that SimpleDateFormat is NOT thread safe.

In Java 8+ I would recommend using the java.time API (e.g. LocalDate).

Answer (score 0):

An example using Java Calendar to compare only the date parts between 2 calendar objects without having to clear() all other calendar fields (MINUTE, MILLISECOND, etc), which gets set when Calendar.getInstance() is called.

I know this thread is old, and this is not a new solution but might be of help to some people.

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();

cal1.set(2018, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
cal2.set(2018, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);

System.out.println(_doesCalendar1DateMatchCalendar2Date(cal1,cal2)); // in this case returns true

private boolean _doesCalendar1DateMatchCalendar2Date(Calendar cal1, Calendar cal2) {
            boolean sameDate = cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR) 
                    && cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) == cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                    && cal1.get(Calendar.DATE) == cal2.get(Calendar.DATE);
            return sameDate;
        }
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: This Answer seems to repeat the content of others such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22609983/642706).